# An ItemsControl is inconsistent with its items source - Gridbox

Tags: c#, wpf, windows

I'm trying to populate a DataGrid by deleting items from another Datagrid that got populated from the database.
Removing them from the original one seems to work flawlessly but AllItems.Remove(allItem) seems to be causing problems.
Whenever I click on Add on the left grid, the right one does get populated by one. When I Try it for a second time it doesn't do anything and the third time it crashes with this line.

> Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: An ItemsControl
>   is inconsistent with its items source.   See the inner exception for
>   more information. ---> System.Exception: Information for developers
>   (use Text Visualizer to read this): This exception was thrown because
>   the generator for control 'System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid
>   Items.Count:3' with name 'AddedItemsGrid' has received sequence of
>   CollectionChanged events that do not agree with the current state of
>   the Items collection.  The following differences were detected:
>   Accumulated count 2 is different from actual count 3.  [Accumulated
>   count is (Count at last Reset + #Adds - #Removes since last Reset).]

If you don't exactly understand what I'm trying here's a brief explanation :

- LeftGrid gets populated by database
- RightGrid gets populated by clicking on the add button on the LeftGrid whilst the items also get removed from the RightGrid
- Clicking on Finish sends the RightGrid collection to the database

[image: My two Datagrids]

View

```
<UserControl x:Class="VivesRental.GUI.View.NewRentalView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:VivesRental.GUI.View"
        mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="0.15*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="0.75*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="0.1*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.5*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.5*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Margin="10px">
            <Run FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="22" Foreground="Black" Text="New Rental for" />
            <Run FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="22" Foreground="Black" Text="{Binding User.Name}" />
        </TextBlock>
        <Button Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Content="Close" Command="{Binding CloseCommand}" Margin="3"></Button>
        <DataGrid x:Name="AllItemsGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding AllItems}" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserResizeRows="False" SelectionMode="Single" CanUserReorderColumns="False" CanUserResizeColumns="False" CanUserSortColumns="False" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Item.Name}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="0.2*">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Button Content="Add" Command="{Binding DataContext.AddItemCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}" CommandParameter="{Binding Id}" Click="OnAddButton" ></Button>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
        <DataGrid x:Name="AddedItemsGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding AddedItems}" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserResizeRows="False" SelectionMode="Single" CanUserReorderColumns="False" CanUserResizeColumns="False" CanUserSortColumns="False" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Item.Name}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="0.2*">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate >
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Button Content="Remove" Command="{Binding DataContext.RemoveItemCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}" CommandParameter="{Binding Id}"></Button>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
        <Button Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Content="Finish" Command="{Binding FinishCommand}" Margin="3"></Button>
    </Grid> 
</UserControl>
```

ViewModel

```
public class NewRentalViewModel : ViewModelBase, IViewModel
    {
        private ItemService itemService;
        private UserService userService;
        private RentalItemService rentalItemService;
        private ICollection<RentalItem> allItems;
        private ICollection<RentalItem> addedItems;
        private User user;
        public RelayCommand CloseCommand { get; private set; }
        public RelayCommand<int> AddItemCommand { get; private set; }
        public RelayCommand<int> RemoveItemCommand { get; private set; }

        public ICollection<RentalItem> AllItems
        {
            get { return allItems; }
            set
            {
                allItems = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged();
            }
        }
        public ICollection<RentalItem> AddedItems
        {
            get { return addedItems; }
            set
            {
                addedItems = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged();
            }
        }
        public User User
        {
            get { return user; }
            set
            {
                user = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public NewRentalViewModel(int userId)
        {
            userService = new UserService();
            itemService = new ItemService();
            User = userService.Get(userId);
            rentalItemService = new RentalItemService();
            InstantiateCommands();
            LoadItems();
        }

        private void InstantiateCommands()
        {
            CloseCommand = new RelayCommand(Close);
            AddItemCommand = new RelayCommand<int>(AddItem);
            RemoveItemCommand = new RelayCommand<int>(RemoveItem);
        }


        private void LoadItems()
        {
            AllItems = rentalItemService.GetAvailableRentalItems(new RentalItemIncludes(){Item = true});
            AddedItems = new List<RentalItem>();
        }

        private void Close()
        {
            var viewModel = new NavigationViewModel();
            var message = new NavigationMessage { ViewModel = viewModel };
            Messenger.Default.Send(message);
        }

        private void AddItem(int itemId)
        {
            foreach (var allItem in AllItems)
            {
                if (allItem.Id == itemId)
                {
                    AllItems.Remove(allItem);
                    AddedItems.Add(allItem);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }


        private void RemoveItem(int itemId)
        {
        }
}
```

View.cs

```
public partial class NewRentalView : UserControl
{
    public NewRentalView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void OnAddButton(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Item item = (Item)((Button)sender).Tag;
        //AllItemsGrid.Items.RemoveAt(item.Id);
        AllItemsGrid.Items.Refresh();
        AddedItemsGrid.Items.Refresh();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would help if this was an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For example, I need to assume that your `ICollection<T>`s are `ObservableCollection`s. Since it's not, it means I can't repeat your problem and will have to guess.

The indication from the error is that WPF is struggling to keep up with the changes being made to the observable collection. This doesn't normally happen.

In the given AddItem relay command, it iterates through the AllItems collection. In the middle of the iteration, it Removes an item from the collection, albeit that it breaks out of the foreach immediately after. This approach can be avoided by using Linq's First method:

```
 private void AddItem(int itemId)
 {
     var allItem = AllItems.First(i=>i.Id == itemId);
     AllItems.Remove(allItem);
     AddedItems.Add(allItem);
 }
```

But you can actually go a step further than that and make life even easier for yourself. In the XAML change the `CommandParameter="{Binding Id}"` to be `CommandParameter="{Binding}"`, and change the parameter of AddItem to be a `RentalItem` rather than an `int` (also change the declaration of the RelayCommand). This way, you don't need to find the item because it is being passed as the parameter.

I'm hoping that doing this will mean the the changes to the collection can be processed in a timely fashion.

Comment: My problem has been solved : I declared my list like thisAddedItems = new List<RentalItem>(); but it actually should be an ObservableCollection like you assumed. Thank you that was really useful.